# Interaction Trigger is not firing on Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

My problem is the interaction triggers are not working on Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus event. But when I do from code behind it works.
I have a Textbox with following code,

```
                      <TextBox
                        Text="{Binding PostRunPlateNotes, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Height="113"
                        Width="Auto"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger
                                EventName="Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                                    Command="{Binding SavePlateNotesCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </TextBox>
```

And in the ViewModel here is the code,

```
#region CommandData
        private ICommand _savePlateNotesCommand;
        public ICommand SavePlateNotesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _savePlateNotesCommand ?? (_savePlateNotesCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSaveClick));
            }
            set
            {
                _savePlateNotesCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SavePlateNotesCommand");
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

In the code behind,

```
 public partial class RunInformationUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Accessors
        public RunInformationParameters RunInfoParams { get; set; }
        public RunInformationViewModel RunViewModel { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public RunInformationUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RunViewModel = null;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void SetParameters(RunInformationParameters parameters)
        {
            this.RunInfoParams = parameters;
            RunViewModel = new RunInformationViewModel(RunInfoParams);
            this.DataContext = RunViewModel;
        }

        #endregion

        #region EventHandlers
        private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (RunViewModel != null)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("runInfoParams");
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChangedEvent
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Problem is when I raise the keyboard lost focus from code behind it works. All the other properties are being bound correctly. But the Interaction Trigger is not working, please help.

Comment: Does it work if you change `Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus` to `LostKeyboardFocus` in the XAML?

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi thanks it works that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally the `EventTrigger` will end up calling `typeof(TextBox).GetEvent("Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus")` in its source code, and that will return `null`, because `TextBox` has no `Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus` event. Since `Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus` is an attached event, hence a WPF/XAML concept, `GetEvent` can't return it and the `EventTrigger` can't subscribe to it.

On the other hand `TextBox` inherits the `LostKeyboardFocus` from `UIElement`, so using that will work.